Create a chain of reactive values in R Shiny
I’m planning to transform a large Excel model into R Shiny. Before starting to code, I’d like to clarify a few aspects. One of these involves translating the dependency logic from Excel, and I’ll explain it using a minimal example below.
Let’s assume we have one input, Input 1, and a simple 1 × 5 data frame. The value for Year 1 is based on real data.


The values for the subsequent years depend on previous years. This relationship is demonstrated in the formula view in Excel below:



Additionally, Input 1 also influences these years:


Given that this method will apply to more than 200 variables, I’m wondering about the best practices for creating reactive values that:

Depend on prior data (e.g., Year 2) or reactive data (e.g., from Year 3 onwards).
Are also affected by Input 1.

I hope I’m not overthinking it—any feedback or suggestions would be much appreciated.

The natural way to express your sample spreadsheet in R would be with two variables:  one for Input1, one for all of row 5.  The row 5 variable depends on Input1.  So it's not really as complicated when you put it in R.

Do you actually need this to be reactive? And do you need to mirror the structure of the spreadsheet? Otherwise a straightforward translation of your model would be Reduce(`*`, c(year1, rep(input1, 4L))). If you need the intermediate values, add the argument accumulate = TRUE. And of course there’s a closed formula for compound interest: year1 * input1 ^ 4.

Hi Konrad, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately yes, In the original Excel model all cells contain at least 2 (often 5 and more) dependences on cells from other positions/sheets. That's why I am exploring the best approach that can be used in R, rather than repeating the Excel logic.

A direct translation would be to convert each formula cell into a reactive:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("input_1", "Input 1", min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1.1),
  numericInput("year_1", "Year 1", value = 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("result"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  year_1 <- reactive(input$year_1)
  year_2 <- reactive(year_1() * input$input_1)
  year_3 <- reactive(year_2() * input$input_1)
  year_4 <- reactive(year_3() * input$input_1)
  output$result <- renderPrint({
    c(year_1(), year_2(), year_3(), year_4())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This is the most general approach but may not be particularly efficient.
If you have a recursive formula it may be better to use a single reactive vector:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("input_1", "Input 1", min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1.1),
  numericInput("year_1", "Year 1", value = 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("result"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  years <- reactive({
    values <- numeric(4)
    values[1] <- input$year_1
    for (i in seq_along(values)[-1]) {
      values[i] <- values[i - 1] * input$input_1
    }
    values
  })
  output$result <- renderPrint(years())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

But a more idiomatic approach in R would be to find an explicit formula, if available:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("input_1", "Input 1", min = 0.1, max = 2, value = 1.1),
  numericInput("year_1", "Year 1", value = 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("result"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  years <- reactive({
    input$year_1 * input$input_1^(seq_len(4) - 1)
  })
  output$result <- renderPrint(years())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

There's tradeoffs to each approach, depending on the details of your application.

Thank you very much Mikko, your examples are exactly what I am after.
